# Не находится пробел в строке

Tags: строки, pascalabc.net

```
var
  a: string;
  x: byte;
begin
  a := '123 333';
  writeln(a);
  x := pos(a, ' ');
  write(x);
end.
```

Программа выводит `0`, что значит, что в строке `a` пробела нет, хотя он присутствует.
В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 4):

Вы перепутали порядок аргументов:

```
Function pos(Substr : String; S : String) : Byte;
```

Должно быть так:

```
var a:string;x:byte;
begin
  a:='123 333';
  writeln(a);
  x:=pos(' ', a);
  writeln(x);
end.
```

Вывод:

> 123 333
>   4

Comment: Жутко глупо...Спасибо)